# DAX with IF and OR

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

I create a DAX to answer the following question.

High priority is any of the following:

- Contracted priority is not L4, or
- MHF/HACCP > 399, or
- Work Priority < 3

High Priority = IF('WO Feedback'[Contracted Priority] > "L4" || 'WO Feedback'[HACCP/MHF] > 399 || 'WO Feedback'[Work Priority] < 3, "YES", "NO")

The following error message popped up
"DAX comparison operations do not support comparing values of type Text with values of type Integer. Consider using the VALUE or FORMAT function to convert one of the values".

Can you please advise the correct Dax and errors in my DAX?

Comment: Hi, could please share the data type of columns i.e. 'WO Feedback'[Contracted Priority], 'WO Feedback'[HACCP/MHF], 'WO Feedback'[Work Priority]?

Comment: @msta42a    Thanks. It works. How do I accept the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error message give you a direct solution; Use VALUE function

```
High Priority = IF('WO Feedback'[Contracted Priority] > "L4" || VALUE('WO Feedback'[HACCP/MHF]) > 399 || VALUE('WO Feedback'[Work Priority]) < 3, "YES", "NO")
```